# Spring-MVC, Hibernate : Contents not deleted from database but method fired

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I am using the @Scheduled method to delete the old information(1 week old) from database. The method was fired, and I got an email, but the contents of the database were not deleted.

Also, I got 4 emails, where I should have got one. Any ideas?

DAO Code in question :

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class NotificationDAOImpl implements NotificationDAO{


    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf){
        this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }

    private Session session;

    public void setSession(Session session){this.session = session;}
    @Override
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 3 3 * * ?")
    public void deleteNotificationsAutoMagically(){
        Emails emails = new Emails();
        emails.sendEmailForNotificationDelete();
        session=this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long nowMinus1Week = now - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
        Timestamp nowMinus1WeekAsTimeStamp = new Timestamp(nowMinus1Week);
        Query query = session.createQuery("delete from NoteLock as nl where nl.timestamp<:limit");
        query.setParameter("limit", nowMinus1WeekAsTimeStamp);
        query.executeUpdate();
        session.flush();
    } 
}
```

Email code :

```
     public void sendEmailForNotificationDelete(){
            final String from = "email@email.de";
            final String emailPassword = "password";

            Properties props = new Properties();

            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "mail.delink-ssl.net");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                    new Authenticator() {
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication(
                                    from, emailPassword);
                        }
                    });
            try {
                MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("myemail@gmail.com"));
                message.setSubject("Notifications were deleted");
                String messageToSend = "Notifications were deleted";
                message.setContent(messageToSend, "text/html;charset=UTF-8");
                Transport.send(message);
            }catch (Exception ignored){

            }
        }
```

Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot.

*Edit*

servlet-context.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
             xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
             xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
             xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:argument-resolvers>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceWebArgumentResolver"/>
        </mvc:argument-resolvers>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>


    <mvc:interceptors>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor"/>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <resources mapping="/resources/" location="/resources/"/>

    <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
                destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <beans:property name="url"
                        value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname"/>
        <beans:property name="username" value="dbuser"/>
        <beans:property name="password" value="dbpass"/>
        <beans:property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
        <beans:property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="20"/>
        <beans:property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Person</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Notes</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Canvas</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Section</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Attachment</beans:value>

                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.GroupAccount</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.GroupMembers</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.GroupCanvas</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.GroupSection</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.GroupNotes</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.GroupAttachments
                </beans:value>

                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Token</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.WaitingMembers
                </beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.NoteHistory</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.GroupNoteHistory
                </beans:value>

                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Feedback</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.UnreadNotes</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.SessionState</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.FeatureRequest
                </beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.FeatureComment
                </beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.FeatureLike</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.OnlineUsers</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.NoteCount</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.NoteLock</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.ChatMessages</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Conversation</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Replies</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Notification</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Statistics</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.PrivateChannel</beans:value>
                <!--<beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.GroupChannels</beans:value>-->
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="connection.pool_size">200</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="c3p0.max_size">200</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="c3p0.timeout">1000</beans:prop>
                   <beans:prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">1000</beans:prop>
                    <beans:prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <task:annotation-driven/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Person beans being here -->
    <beans:bean id="personDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.PersonDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="personService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.PersonServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="personDAO" ref="personDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <!--  <beans:bean id="bayeux" class="org.cometd.server.BayeuxServerImpl" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
          <beans:property name="transports">
              <beans:list>
                  <beans:bean id="jsonTransport" class="org.cometd.server.transport.JSONTransport">
                      <beans:constructor-arg ref="bayeux"/>
                  </beans:bean>
                  <beans:bean id="jsonpTransport" class="org.cometd.server.transport.JSONPTransport">
                      <beans:constructor-arg ref="bayeux"/>
                  </beans:bean>
              </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
      </beans:bean>-->

    <!-- Group Account beans begin here -->

    <beans:bean id="groupAccountDAO"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.GroupAccountDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="groupAccountService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.GroupAccountServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="groupAccountDAO" ref="groupAccountDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!--Group Members bean begin here -->
    <beans:bean id="groupMembersDAO"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.GroupMembersDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="groupMembersService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.GroupMembersServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="groupMembersDAO" ref="groupMembersDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Notes bean begin here -->
    <beans:bean id="notesDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.NotesDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="notesService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.NotesServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="notesDAO" ref="notesDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!--GroupNotes begin here -->

    <beans:bean id="groupNotesDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.GroupNotesDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="groupNotesService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.GroupNotesServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="groupNotesDAO" ref="groupNotesDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <!-- Canvas Beans begin here -->

    <beans:bean id="canvasDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.CanvasDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="canvasService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.CanvasServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="canvasDAO" ref="canvasDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!--Group Canvas beans begin here -->
    <beans:bean id="groupCanvasDAO"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.GroupCanvasDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="groupCanvasService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.GroupCanvasServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="groupCanvasDAO" ref="groupCanvasDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Section beans begin here -->
    <beans:bean id="sectionDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.SectionDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="sectionService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.SectionServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="sectionDAO" ref="sectionDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Group Section beans begin here -->
    <beans:bean id="groupSectionDAO"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.GroupSectionDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="groupSectionService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.GroupSectionServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="groupSectionDAO" ref="groupSectionDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="tokenDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.TokenDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="tokenService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.TokenServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="tokenDAO" ref="tokenDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="attachDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.AttachmentDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="attachService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.AttachmentServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="attachmentDAO" ref="attachDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="mattachDAO"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.GroupAttachmentsDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="mattachService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.GroupAttachmentsServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="groupAttachmentsDAO" ref="mattachDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="waitingDAO"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.WaitingMembersDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="waitingService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.WaitingMembersServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="waitingMembersDAO" ref="waitingDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="historyDAO"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.NoteHistoryDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="historyService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.NoteHistoryServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="noteHistoryDAO" ref="historyDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="mhistoryDAO"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.GroupNoteHistoryDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="mhistoryService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.GroupNoteHistoryServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="groupNoteHistoryDAO" ref="mhistoryDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="feedbackDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.FeedbackDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="feedbackService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.FeedbackServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="feedbackDAO" ref="feedbackDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="unreadDAO"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.UnreadNotesDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="unreadService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.UnreadNotesServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="unreadNotesDAO" ref="unreadDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="sessionStateDAO"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.SessionStateDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="sessionService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.SessionStateServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionStateDAO" ref="sessionStateDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="featuresDAO"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.FeatureRequestDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="featuresService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.FeatureRequestServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="featureRequestDAO" ref="featuresDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="featureCommentDAO"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.FeatureCommentDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="featureCommentService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.FeatureCommentServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="featureCommentDAO" ref="featureCommentDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="featureLikeDAO"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.FeatureLikeDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="featureLikeService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.FeatureLikeServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="featureLikeDAO" ref="featureLikeDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="onlineUsersDAO"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.OnlineUsersDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="onlineUsersService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.OnlineUsersServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="onlineUsersDAO" ref="onlineUsersDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="noteCountDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.NoteCountDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="noteCountService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.NoteCountServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="noteCountDAO" ref="noteCountDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="noteLockDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.NoteLockDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="noteLockService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.NoteLockServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="noteLockDAO" ref="noteLockDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="chatDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.ChatMessagesDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="chatService" class="com.journaldev.spring.service.ChatMessagesServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="chatDAO" ref="chatDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="conversationDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.ConversationDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="conversationService" class="com.journaldev.spring.service.ConversationServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="conversationDAO" ref="conversationDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="repliesDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.RepliesDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="repliesService" class="com.journaldev.spring.service.RepliesServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="repliesDAO" ref="repliesDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="notificationDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.NotificationDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="notificationService" class="com.journaldev.spring.service.NotificationServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="notificationDAO" ref="notificationDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="statisticsDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.StatisticsDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="statisticsService" class="com.journaldev.spring.service.StatisticsServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="statisticsDAO" ref="statisticsDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="privateChannelDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.PrivateChannelDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="privateChannelService" class="com.journaldev.spring.service.PrivateChannelServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="privateChannelDAO" ref="privateChannelDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


 <!--   <beans:bean id="groupChannelsDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.GroupChannelsDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="groupChannelsService" class="com.journaldev.spring.service.GroupChannelsServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="groupChannelsDAO" ref="groupChannelsDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>-->

    <!--<beans:bean id="chatBean" class="com.journaldev.spring.chat.ChatServiceImpl"/>-->

    <!--Login bean -->
    <beans:bean id="LoginServiceImpl"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.LoginServiceImpl"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev.spring"/>

    <!-- locale -->
    <beans:bean id="messageSource"
                class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:/locale/messages"/>
        <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>

    <!-- default locale -->
    <beans:bean id="localeResolver"
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <beans:property name="defaultLocale" value="de"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Change locale via url. -->
    <beans:bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <beans:property name="paramName" value="lang"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="handlerMapping"
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping">
        <beans:property name="interceptors">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor"/>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean class="com.journaldev.spring.service.DoNotTruncateMyUrls"/>

    <beans:bean id="multipartResolver"
                class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="52428800"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <beans:property name="messageConverters" ref="jsonMessageConverter"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter"
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: i'm not sure, but may be a commit() is needed on query in your DAO class? I don't know if the flush() do the commit().

Comment: For some reason your class looks flawed, you shouldn't store the `Session` in a instance variable. If `getCurrentSession` is working I assume your scheduled class is `@Transactional` if not your setup is wrong and you have to either fix your setup or do manual transaction management.

Comment: @We are Borg: From the session api for flush "Force this session to flush. Must be called at the end of a unit of work, before committing the transaction and closing the session "

Comment: @WeareBorg flush != commit. The fact that a query is issued doesn't mean it is committed... After a flush you can still do a rollback...

Comment: Please add your configuration for hibernate and scheduling.

Comment: Please add the full hibernate configuration, do you have a `hibernate.cfg.xml` or `hibernate.properties`?

Comment: Make sure that your query is actually deleting something. The `executeUpdate` method is returning the number of rows touched. Also instead of the `TimeStamp` just add the long as parameter (hibernate takes care of the conversion).

Comment: Hmm your configuration is trying very hard to duplicate things (but that is for a different question :) ) and your code can vastly be improved. Can you post the `NoteLock` class?

Comment: @M.Deinum : Everything I have for hibernate I have put in servlet-context.xml which is added at bottom of main post. The query is not deleting anything.  I have changed it to add Long now. What of NoteLock class, model, service, dao?

Comment: Which `FlushMode` are you using?

Comment: Please add the `Notelock` class.

Comment: @M.Deinum : I had to put in pastebin, as the character limit of SO is over. Model : http://pastebin.com/5XVgR9M5
DAO : http://pastebin.com/ZZTQQf7C
Service : http://pastebin.com/nuP4NGR7

Comment: I would say you are using the wrong data type, you would also be missing an annotation `@Temporal` for the field to indicate it is a date field. What is the type of the field in the database?

Comment: @M.Deinum : I am confused, I am trying to delete notifications, not NoteLocks. Type of field in DB is TimeStamp without timezone. I am using PostgreSQL. I don't have atTemporal annotation for Notification model. I am adding notification model in pastebin, here it is : http://pastebin.com/nzYiwE4N

Comment: Then delete notifications... Your query is for `NoteLock` not for `Notification`s...

Comment: @M.Deinum : OMG, that was the error.. so hopeless of me.

Comment: Voting to close this question as this was basically just a typo.

Comment: @M.Deinum : Before you leave, can you tell me why I got 4 emails exactly at 3:03, instead of only one at 3:03.

Comment: Well 1 thing you are duplicating beans, so you already have 2 running instances, next you probably are loading the configuration twice, basically duplicating everything. Hence 4 instances of the dao, 4 emails. 2 of them I suspect crash with a `NullPointerException` on the `SessionFactory`... As I mentioned your code and configuration can vastly improved...

Comment: I am wondering if you always vote down to answers, which may not tell EXACT root cause of issue, but try to help you!

Comment: @Raúl : I did not downvote any answer, dunno who did it...sorry...

Comment: @M.Deinum : I have created a new question with proper structure and details. I request you to have a look when you have free time, thanks.  Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30399338/spring-mvc-creating-a-good-infrastructureconfiguration-and-avoiding-duplicat

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be that `@Scheduled` and `@Transactional` don't play well together if they are declared for the same method.

Try to externalize the scheduled method into another bean and use an autowired instance of your dao (which has the transactional method)

Answer (score 0):

I think you @Transactional annotation isn't "taking effect". Reasons being:

You are defining beans in the XML file, but also using `<context:component-scan>` declaration.  I think if you add all the expected packages for `<context:component-scan>` then your problem will get fixed, and also you won't have to define beans in your xml.

In your DAO code, write some logging statement to check if Transaction is active. You can use [TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationManager.html#isActualTransactionActive--) method to detect whether any Transaction is going on or not.

Answer (score -1):

To start with:

1. Put your deletion code into try-catch; & within try, after query execution, place send mail code.
2. Check if you have expected records in that table & your query is fine. Check for a different column (may be id) to start with, using a query browser. Later change your query to this one.

Comment: @downvoter - as there were already 10+ comments, I posted it as answer. & I think its helpful as well. Now why a downvote?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but that's because you just provided debugging guidelines rather than stating the true issue(s) behind the problem.