# Spring-MVC : Creating a good infrastructure(configuration) and avoiding duplicates

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactions

I am working on a Spring-MVC application since some time. Recently I ran into some problems with @Scheduled methods, and I noticed that the whole configuration is getting loaded 4 times. Because of that the @Scheduled methods are getting called 4 times.

The 3 configurations which are not correct, die out with NullPointerException(is what I was told on SO), and the one survives. I am very much interested to know how can I configure my project properly, so there is only one configuration which is loaded, and not 4, and learn about Spring-MVC, Spring in the process.

As the servlet-context is large, I am posting web.xml on pastebin, so I can have place to put JAVA code as well.

Servlet-context.xml :

```
  <context:annotation-config/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:argument-resolvers>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceWebArgumentResolver"/>
        </mvc:argument-resolvers>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor"/>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <resources mapping="/resources/" location="/resources/"/>

    <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
                destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <beans:property name="url"
                        value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname"/>
        <beans:property name="username" value="dbuser"/>
        <beans:property name="password" value="dbpass"/>
        <beans:property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
        <beans:property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="20"/>
        <beans:property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Person</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Notes</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Canvas</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Section</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Attachment</beans:value>

                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.GroupAccount</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.GroupMembers</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.GroupCanvas</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.GroupSection</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.GroupNotes</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.GroupAttachments
                </beans:value>

                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Token</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.WaitingMembers
                </beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.NoteHistory</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.GroupNoteHistory
                </beans:value>

                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Feedback</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.UnreadNotes</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.SessionState</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.FeatureRequest
                </beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.FeatureComment
                </beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.FeatureLike</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.OnlineUsers</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.NoteCount</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.NoteLock</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.ChatMessages</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Conversation</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Replies</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Notification</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Statistics</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.PrivateChannel</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.GroupChannels</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="connection.pool_size">200</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="c3p0.max_size">200</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="c3p0.timeout">1000</beans:prop>
             <!--   <beans:prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">1000</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</beans:prop>-->
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <task:annotation-driven/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Person beans being here -->
    <beans:bean id="personDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.PersonDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="personService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.PersonServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="personDAO" ref="personDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <!--  <beans:bean id="bayeux" class="org.cometd.server.BayeuxServerImpl" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
          <beans:property name="transports">
              <beans:list>
                  <beans:bean id="jsonTransport" class="org.cometd.server.transport.JSONTransport">
                      <beans:constructor-arg ref="bayeux"/>
                  </beans:bean>
                  <beans:bean id="jsonpTransport" class="org.cometd.server.transport.JSONPTransport">
                      <beans:constructor-arg ref="bayeux"/>
                  </beans:bean>
              </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
      </beans:bean>-->

    <!-- Group Account beans begin here -->

    <beans:bean id="groupAccountDAO"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.GroupAccountDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="groupAccountService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.GroupAccountServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="groupAccountDAO" ref="groupAccountDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!--Group Members bean begin here -->
    <beans:bean id="groupMembersDAO"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.GroupMembersDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="groupMembersService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.GroupMembersServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="groupMembersDAO" ref="groupMembersDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Notes bean begin here -->
    <beans:bean id="notesDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.NotesDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="notesService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.NotesServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="notesDAO" ref="notesDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!--GroupNotes begin here -->

    <beans:bean id="groupNotesDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.GroupNotesDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="groupNotesService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.GroupNotesServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="groupNotesDAO" ref="groupNotesDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <!-- Canvas Beans begin here -->

    <beans:bean id="canvasDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.CanvasDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="canvasService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.CanvasServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="canvasDAO" ref="canvasDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!--Group Canvas beans begin here -->
    <beans:bean id="groupCanvasDAO"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.GroupCanvasDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="groupCanvasService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.GroupCanvasServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="groupCanvasDAO" ref="groupCanvasDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Section beans begin here -->
    <beans:bean id="sectionDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.SectionDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="sectionService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.SectionServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="sectionDAO" ref="sectionDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Group Section beans begin here -->
    <beans:bean id="groupSectionDAO"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.GroupSectionDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="groupSectionService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.GroupSectionServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="groupSectionDAO" ref="groupSectionDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="tokenDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.TokenDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="tokenService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.TokenServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="tokenDAO" ref="tokenDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="attachDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.AttachmentDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="attachService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.AttachmentServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="attachmentDAO" ref="attachDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="mattachDAO"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.GroupAttachmentsDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="mattachService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.GroupAttachmentsServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="groupAttachmentsDAO" ref="mattachDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="waitingDAO"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.WaitingMembersDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="waitingService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.WaitingMembersServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="waitingMembersDAO" ref="waitingDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="historyDAO"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.NoteHistoryDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="historyService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.NoteHistoryServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="noteHistoryDAO" ref="historyDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="mhistoryDAO"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.GroupNoteHistoryDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="mhistoryService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.GroupNoteHistoryServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="groupNoteHistoryDAO" ref="mhistoryDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="feedbackDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.FeedbackDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="feedbackService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.FeedbackServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="feedbackDAO" ref="feedbackDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="unreadDAO"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.UnreadNotesDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="unreadService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.UnreadNotesServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="unreadNotesDAO" ref="unreadDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="sessionStateDAO"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.SessionStateDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="sessionService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.SessionStateServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionStateDAO" ref="sessionStateDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="featuresDAO"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.FeatureRequestDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="featuresService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.FeatureRequestServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="featureRequestDAO" ref="featuresDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="featureCommentDAO"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.FeatureCommentDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="featureCommentService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.FeatureCommentServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="featureCommentDAO" ref="featureCommentDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="featureLikeDAO"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.FeatureLikeDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="featureLikeService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.FeatureLikeServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="featureLikeDAO" ref="featureLikeDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="onlineUsersDAO"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.OnlineUsersDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="onlineUsersService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.OnlineUsersServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="onlineUsersDAO" ref="onlineUsersDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="noteCountDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.NoteCountDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="noteCountService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.NoteCountServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="noteCountDAO" ref="noteCountDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="noteLockDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.NoteLockDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
                        ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="noteLockService"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.NoteLockServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="noteLockDAO" ref="noteLockDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="chatDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.ChatMessagesDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="chatService" class="com.journaldev.spring.service.ChatMessagesServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="chatDAO" ref="chatDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="conversationDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.ConversationDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="conversationService" class="com.journaldev.spring.service.ConversationServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="conversationDAO" ref="conversationDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="repliesDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.RepliesDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="repliesService" class="com.journaldev.spring.service.RepliesServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="repliesDAO" ref="repliesDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="notificationDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.NotificationDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="notificationService" class="com.journaldev.spring.service.NotificationServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="notificationDAO" ref="notificationDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="statisticsDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.StatisticsDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="statisticsService" class="com.journaldev.spring.service.StatisticsServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="statisticsDAO" ref="statisticsDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="privateChannelDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.PrivateChannelDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="privateChannelService" class="com.journaldev.spring.service.PrivateChannelServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="privateChannelDAO" ref="privateChannelDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>


   <beans:bean id="groupChannelsDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.GroupChannelsDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="groupChannelsService" class="com.journaldev.spring.service.GroupChannelsServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="groupChannelsDAO" ref="groupChannelsDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!--<beans:bean id="chatBean" class="com.journaldev.spring.chat.ChatServiceImpl"/>-->

    <!--Login bean -->
    <beans:bean id="LoginServiceImpl"
                class="com.journaldev.spring.service.LoginServiceImpl"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev.spring"/>

    <!-- locale -->
    <beans:bean id="messageSource"
                class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:/locale/messages"/>
        <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>

    <!-- default locale -->
    <beans:bean id="localeResolver"
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <beans:property name="defaultLocale" value="de"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Change locale via url. -->
    <beans:bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <beans:property name="paramName" value="lang"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="handlerMapping"
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping">
        <beans:property name="interceptors">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor"/>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean class="com.journaldev.spring.service.DoNotTruncateMyUrls"/>

    <beans:bean id="multipartResolver"
                class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="52428800"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <beans:property name="messageConverters" ref="jsonMessageConverter"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter"
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>

</beans:beans>
```

As said, [here](http://pastebin.com/sLt3yFU5) is the URL for web.xml and [here](http://pastebin.com/iUR0kLhL) is security-application.context.xml

Throughout the project, the model looks like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "canvas")
public class Canvas {

    @Id
    @Column(name="canvasid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "canvas_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "canvas_gen",sequenceName = "canvas_seq")
    @Index(name = "canvasid")
    private int canvasid;
//Other variables, mappings, getters, setters
}
```

DAO looks like this throughtout the project :

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class CanvasDAOImpl implements CanvasDAO{


    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf){
        this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }

    private Session session;

    public void setSession(Session session){this.session = session;}

   @overrride
   public returnType methodName(params..){
        session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

}
}
```

And finally, my service layer looks like this :

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CanvasServiceImpl implements CanvasService {
 private CanvasDAO canvasDAO;

    public void setCanvasDAO(CanvasDAO canvasDAO) {
        this.canvasDAO = canvasDAO;
    }
//methods
}
```

I have maintained the same structure throughout the java files. Why is that my configuration is loaded 4 times instead of 1. Any suggestions overall for optimizations. Thanks.

*Edit*

My service looks like this :

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class AttachmentServiceImpl implements AttachmentService{

    @Autowired
    private AttachmentDAO attachmentDAO;
// The guy below stays or not? why?
 public void setAttachmentDAO(AttachmentDAO attachmentDAO){
        this.attachmentDAO = attachmentDAO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of things that can be improved with your code and configuration. Lets start with your dao, don't store the `Session` in a instance variable and I strongly suggest to use constructor injection for the required dependencies. Taking this into account your dao(s) should look something like this.

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class CanvasDAOImpl implements CanvasDAO{

    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public CanvasDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory=sessionFactory;
    }

   @overrride
   public returnType methodName(params..){
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        // Do stuff with the session.
    }
}
```

No more setters (especially not for the `Session`!) just a plain class. The same applies for the `@Service` classes.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CanvasServiceImpl implements CanvasService {

    private final CanvasDAO canvasDAO;

    public CanvasServiceImpl(CanvasDAO canvasDAO) {
        this.canvasDAO=canvasDAO;
    }

    //methods
}
```

In your configuration you have explicitly defined all your `@Repository` and `@Service` beans. You also have a `<context:component-scan />` which already detects all `@Component`s. Remove all explicitly declared `@Repository` and `@Service` beans. This will really clean up your configuration!.

In your hibernate configuration the `c3p0` and `connection` properties are useless as you are injecting a `DataSource` and hibernate is't managing it but Spring is. Remove those lines. Also to cleanup this configuration further instead of specifying each and every class it needs to proces add `packagesToScan` so it will automatically detect `@Entity` annotated beans.

`<context:annotation-config />` is already implied by the use of `<context:component-scan />` so you can remove it as it basically duplicates things.

You have explicitly defined a `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` which doesn't do anything as there is already one registered by `<mvc:annotation-driven />`. It only takes up memory, the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` is registered automatically of Jackson2 is detected on the class path so no need to do that.

Chancing the `Locale` doesn't work for all URLs as you forgot to register the interceptor with the `<mvc:annotation-driven />` element.

When applying all that advice to your classes and configuration the remaining configuration looks like this.

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev.spring"/>
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:argument-resolvers>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceWebArgumentResolver"/>
        </mvc:argument-resolvers>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor"/>
        <beans:ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <resources mapping="/resources/" location="/resources/"/>

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
                destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <beans:property name="url"
                        value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname"/>
        <beans:property name="username" value="dbuser"/>
        <beans:property name="password" value="dbpass"/>
        <beans:property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
        <beans:property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="20"/>
        <beans:property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.journaldev.spring.model" />       
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</beans:prop>
             <!--   <beans:prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">1000</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</beans:prop>-->
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <task:annotation-driven/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>



    <!--  <beans:bean id="bayeux" class="org.cometd.server.BayeuxServerImpl" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
          <beans:property name="transports">
              <beans:list>
                  <beans:bean id="jsonTransport" class="org.cometd.server.transport.JSONTransport">
                      <beans:constructor-arg ref="bayeux"/>
                  </beans:bean>
                  <beans:bean id="jsonpTransport" class="org.cometd.server.transport.JSONPTransport">
                      <beans:constructor-arg ref="bayeux"/>
                  </beans:bean>
              </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
      </beans:bean>-->


    <!-- locale -->
    <beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:/locale/messages"/>
        <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <!-- default locale -->
    <beans:bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <beans:property name="defaultLocale" value="de"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Change locale via url. -->
    <beans:bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <beans:property name="paramName" value="lang"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping">
        <beans:property name="interceptors">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor"/>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean class="com.journaldev.spring.service.DoNotTruncateMyUrls"/>

    <beans:bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="52428800"/>
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

However you really should split things up in what is loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` basically everything BUT `@Controller`s and what is loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` just `@Controller`s and web related beans.

So the `servlet-context.xml` should look something like this.

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev.spring" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:argument-resolvers>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceWebArgumentResolver"/>
        </mvc:argument-resolvers>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor"/>
        <beans:ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <resources mapping="/resources/" location="/resources/"/>

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- locale -->
    <beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:/locale/messages"/>
        <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <!-- default locale -->
    <beans:bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <beans:property name="defaultLocale" value="de"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Change locale via url. -->
    <beans:bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <beans:property name="paramName" value="lang"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping">
        <beans:property name="interceptors">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor"/>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean class="com.journaldev.spring.service.DoNotTruncateMyUrls"/>

    <beans:bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="52428800"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

Then add what was removed and a `<context:component-scan />` (or modify it) to the `root-context.xml`.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev.spring">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>

<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
            destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <beans:property name="url"
                    value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname"/>
    <beans:property name="username" value="dbuser"/>
    <beans:property name="password" value="dbpass"/>
    <beans:property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
    <beans:property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="20"/>
    <beans:property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false"/>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
<beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.journaldev.spring.model" />       
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</beans:prop>
         <!--   <beans:prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">1000</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</beans:prop>-->
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<task:annotation-driven/>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
</beans:bean>

<!--  <beans:bean id="bayeux" class="org.cometd.server.BayeuxServerImpl" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
      <beans:property name="transports">
          <beans:list>
              <beans:bean id="jsonTransport" class="org.cometd.server.transport.JSONTransport">
                  <beans:constructor-arg ref="bayeux"/>
              </beans:bean>
              <beans:bean id="jsonpTransport" class="org.cometd.server.transport.JSONPTransport">
                  <beans:constructor-arg ref="bayeux"/>
              </beans:bean>
          </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
  </beans:bean>-->
```

Remove the `<import resource="servlet-context.xml" />` from your `security-context.xml`.

Finally let the `DispatcherServlet` load the `servlet-context.xml` instead of the `security-context.xml`.

Now as you aren't loading beans twice per context anymore you should have a reduced memory footprint and you shouldn't have 4 scheduled jobs any more. Also your `Email` class should, ideally, also be a Spring managed bean and I would suggest using the `JavaMailSender` API which simplifies sending emails.

So basically the task ahead for you is to mainly remove things, you will end up with less code and less configuration and still achieve the same.

*For more hands-on-advice I'm for hire ;)...*

Comment: That answer was awesome. Thank u so much...i will keep what u said in mind.. And i am sure i understood so much as i understood in a months... Thanks a lot. I am starting to implement this now. And arrange a bounty.

Comment: Hello Sir, Can you please check out this question regarding Spring-MVC and Maven. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40125973/spring-maven-nullpointer-exception-when-calling-methods-from-local-spring-mvc   . Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The point of using annotations is to remove the need for xml configuration. If you are using the Spring `@Service` and `@Repository` annotations then you can remove all the service and dao definitions from the xml posted above and replace them with with one line.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="x.y.z.service, x.y.z.repository" />
```

You can then update all your service classes to be like below using the `@Autowired` annotation to have Spring inject the relevant DAO:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CanvasServiceImpl implements CanvasService {

    @Autowired
    private CanvasDAO canvasDAO;
}
```

You also load the Spring security context multiple times in your web.xml. Once via The ContextLoaderListener and once via the RequestDispatcher configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml,/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/security-applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>1440</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    ...

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/security-applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>

</web-app>
```

And then, just to finish things off you also import the web application configuration in the security context each time it is loaded.

```
<import resource="servlet-context.xml" />
```

I would normally configure as outlined here. I believe this is considered best practice. Essentially you have the Dispatcher Servlet initialize only the web related stuff. You have the Listener initialize the non-web stuff.

http://simone-folino.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/dispatcherservlet-vs.html

Comment: I am changing it to autowired now. Should I remove the one from ContextLoader or RequestDispatcher?

Comment: I have added at bottom of main post some code, can you please check

Comment: And, no. You don't need setters when using Autowired as Spring can use the field (even if private). You may however want to leave the setter in case you wanted to set a Mock or Stub if unit testing outside of Spring.