# can't get data from database using spring-mvc and hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

this is my code:
my model class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="admin")
public class Admin extends Profile{
    public Admin(){}

    public Admin(String mail, String name, String lastName, String password, Date birthDate, int gsm){
        super(mail, name, lastName, password, birthDate, gsm);
    }
}
```

the DAO class:

```
@Repository
public class AdminDAO {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AdminDAO.class);

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf){
        this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Admin> listAdmins() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Admin> adminsList = session.createQuery("from Admin").list();
        for(Admin a : adminsList){
            logger.info("Admin List::"+a);
        }
        return adminsList;
    }
}
```

my Service class:

```
@Service

    public class AdminService {

        @Autowired
        private AdminDAO adminDAO;

        public void setAdminDAO(AdminDAO adminDAO) {
            this.adminDAO = adminDAO;
        }
        @Transactional
        public List<Admin> listAdmins() {
            return this.adminDAO.listAdmins();
        }
    }
```

when i run my code i get this error message:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at com.journaldev.spring.dao.AdminDAO.listAdmins(AdminDAO.java:38)

i added an admin manually in my database, but it still showing the null pointer exception
what i am doing wrong ??
note: i have another class that works fine, it gets all entities and when the database is empty, it doesn't generate null pointer exception

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt no it's not !! please read the question first

Comment: I have read the question and you have clearly not read the duplicate. If you had read it, you would have told us which variable or field was `null` and possibly you would have asked why because you can't find that out. You would also not have posted 300 lines of code, but just the part that was relevant.

Comment: ok i will edit my post

Comment: You should improvise your setup and config, this thread should help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30399338/spring-mvc-creating-a-good-infrastructureconfiguration-and-avoiding-duplicat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the `@Autowired` or the `@Inject` annotation for the setter method for `adminDAO`. It has to be

```
@Autowired
public void setAdminDAO(AdminDAO adminDAO) {
    this.adminDAO = adminDAO;
}
```

You have to annotate all dependencies of your Bean with `@Autowired` or `@Inject`.

Comment: ok i added '@Autowired' annotation in my AdminService class
now the exception is generated in DAO class and not in Service class

Comment: You have to add `@Autowired` also to the setter of `sessionFactory`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: thank you so muuuuch !! what did change after i added these annotations? can u please explain me :)

Comment: The `adminDAO` and the `sessionFactory` properties where `null` and hence the runtime throws a `NullPointerException` when you try to access this (for example in the `listAdmins` method). `@Autowire` or `@Inject` tells the spring container to inject a apropriate value if known and voila the propertie isn't `null` anymore. For more details have a lookl at the [spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html).